# Which is the domain of the probability density function of $X^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \text{ for each } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
We want to find the probability density function of $Y := X^2$.

I already found the expression of $f_Y$ (correct me if I'm wrong, please):

We know that
$$F_Y(y) = P[Y \leq y] = P\left[X^2 \leq y\right] = P\left[\left|X\right| \leq \sqrt{y}\right] = \\$$
$$P\left[-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\right] =^{(1)} P\left[-\sqrt{y} < X \leq \sqrt{y}\right] = F_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right) - F_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right).$$
Hence
$$f_Y(y) =^{(2)} F'_Y(y) = F'_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = f_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi y}}e^\frac{-\left|y\right|}{2}.$$

But where is the domain of $f_Y$? I mean, obviously $y > 0$, so would $\mathbb{R}^+$ be the domain of the function? I think I could determine the support of $Y$ before finding the expression, but how?

Other secondary questions:

(1) This is because $P[X = -\sqrt{y}] = 0$, right?

(2) I think I can only say this if $f_Y$ is continuous. Why would I assume continuity?

Comment: That $X$ has zero probability mass everywhere is besides the point. After all, $X$ is a continuous r.v.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see very well the absolute value thing, because we have to
\begin{align*}
F_{Y}(y) & = P( Y \leq y) \\
& = P(X^2 \leq y) \\
& = P(|X| \leq \sqrt{y}) \\
& = P(- \sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) \\
& = F_{X}(\sqrt{y}) - F_{X}(-\sqrt{y}) \\
f_{Y}(y) & =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} f_{X}(\sqrt{y}) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} f_{X}(-\sqrt{y}) \\
& = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y} \sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{- (\sqrt{y})^2 /2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y} \sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{- (-\sqrt{y})^2 /2} \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y} \sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{- y /2}
\end{align*}
Now, for the support of $Y = X^2$ we can do two things. The first is to graph the transformation $y = x^2$, this is

[image]

like $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we focus on the $y$ axis, but it goes from $0$ to $\infty$, the $y > 0$. And another somewhat less formal is to separate the interval and evaluate it in the transformation.
$$
A_1 = (-\infty, 0) , \quad A_2 = \{0\}, \quad A_3 = (0,\infty)
$$

we evaluate

$$
\lim_{x \to - \infty} x^2 = \infty
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 = \infty
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = 0
$$
then $y > 0$. Well, if we square all the possible values ​​of $x > 0$, they are still $x > 0$

Remember that in practice it doesn't matter if you touch $0$ or not, that can be easily fixed.